# XML parsing with XSLT

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

Hi I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserStaging>
            <NeuroRKStaging>
               <Stage Type="REM" Start="0" />
               <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="150" />
               <Stage Type="Movement" Start="3030" />
               <Stage Type="Wake" Start="3150" />
               <Stage Type="Stage2" Start="4680" />
               <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="5340" />
               <Stage Type="Movement" Start="6090" />
               <Stage Type="Wake" Start="6480" />
               <Stage Type="Stage1" Start="9330" />
               <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="10290" />
            </NeuroRKStaging>
</UserStaging>
```

And I have to get it in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stages>
    <epoch><epoch_start>0</epoch_start><epoch_end>150</epoch_end><stage>REM</stage></epoch>   
    <epoch><epoch_start>150</epoch_start><epoch_end>3150</epoch_end><stage>NREM3</stage></epoch>
    <epoch><epoch_start>3150</epoch_start><epoch_end>4680</epoch_end><stage>Wake</stage></epoch>
    <epoch><epoch_start>4680</epoch_start><epoch_end>5340</epoch_end><stage>NREM2</stage></epoch>
    <epoch><epoch_start>5340</epoch_start><epoch_end>6480</epoch_end><stage>NREM3</stage></epoch>
    <epoch><epoch_start>6480</epoch_start><epoch_end>9330</epoch_end><stage>Wake</stage></epoch>
    <epoch><epoch_start>9330</epoch_start><epoch_end>10290</epoch_end><stage>NREM1</stage></epoch>
    <epoch><epoch_start>10290</epoch_start><epoch_end>99999</epoch_end><stage>NREM3</stage></epoch>
</stages>
```

There are 5 types/stages

```
Stage1 transforms to NREM1
Stage2 transforms to NREM2
Stage3 transforms to NREM3
REM remains REM
Wake remains Wake
```

All lines with Type="Movement" should be deleted and only after that the data should be transformed. 
The "Start" of every following Stage is going to be the "epoch_end" of the one before. For the last epoch the epoch_end should be 99999

How would a xsl stylesheet look like to do that?

Comment: Well, which XSLT processor do you use, which XSLT version can you use? Might be a good job for XSLT 3's `xsl:iterate select="Stage[not(@Type = 'Movement')]"` but if if we donated you some code for free you should at least tell us before which XSLT version you can use.

Comment: I can use version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3's `xsl:iterate` you can pass on the previously processed item and then output it with the right start and end values, also taking care of the last item with `xsl:on-completion`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="default-end" as="xs:integer" select="99999"/>

  <xsl:param name="type-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'Stage1' : 'NREM1', 'Stage2' : 'NREM2', 'Stage3' : 'NREM3' }"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="NeuroRKStaging">
      <stages>
          <xsl:iterate select="Stage[not(@Type = 'Movement')]">
              <xsl:param name="previous" as="element()?" select="()"/>
              <xsl:on-completion>
                  <xsl:if test="$previous">
                      <epoch>
                      <epoch_start>{$previous/@Start}</epoch_start>
                      <epoch_end>{$default-end}</epoch_end>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="$previous/@Type"/>
                  </epoch>
                  </xsl:if>
              </xsl:on-completion>
              <xsl:if test="$previous">
                  <epoch>
                      <epoch_start>{$previous/@Start}</epoch_start>
                      <epoch_end>{@Start}</epoch_end>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="$previous/@Type"/>
                  </epoch>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:next-iteration>
                  <xsl:with-param name="previous" select="."/>
              </xsl:next-iteration>
          </xsl:iterate>
      </stages>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Stage/@Type">
      <stage>{.}</stage>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Stage/@Type[map:contains($type-map, .)]">
      <stage>{$type-map(.)}</stage>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y8Z/1

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Could you please edit your code to include <quality>Good</quality> in each epoch? How would I do that?

Comment: You have an example containing the literal result elements (like `epoch` or `epoch_start`) in the XSLT code so now you should start experimenting on your own, adding a further literal result element should be something you can figure out, it is not more complicated than typing it in the comment you have written, so give it some try. If you really fail to achieve that then post a new question with details of what you attempted and how it failed.