# Transform XML data with XSLT

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

I have the following xml data

```
<UserStaging>
            <NeuroRKStaging>
               <Stage Type="REM" Start="0" />
               <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="150" />
               <Stage Type="Movement" Start="3030" />
               <Stage Type="Wake" Start="3150" />
               <Stage Type="Stage2" Start="4680" />
               <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="5340" />
               <Stage Type="Movement" Start="6090" />
               <Stage Type="Wake" Start="6480" />
               <Stage Type="Stage1" Start="9330" />
               <Stage Type="Stage3" Start="10290" />
            </NeuroRKStaging>
</UserStaging>
```

I have to get it into following format:

```
REM 150
N2 3150
Wake 4680
N2 5340
N3 6480
Wake 9330
N1 10290
N3 50000
```

There are five "types":

```
Stage1 transforms to N1
Stage2 transforms to N2
Stage3 transforms to N3
REM remains REM
Wake remains Wake
```

All lines with Type="Movement" should be deleted and only after that the data should be transformed. The "Start" of every following Stage is going to be the number behind the "type" before it. For the last "type" (in this exemple N3) the number should be 50000

How would a xsl stylesheet look like to do that? I am able to use up to XSLT version 3. Thanks for any help!

Comment: the line in this exemple "N2 3150" should be "N3 3150". sorry for the typo

Comment: How REM 150 in your exaple?

Comment: Please review your question again i think you have misplaced the data:

Comment: I tried but due to not clear i am unable to achieve desired output. Please see the link and hope you will get some idea: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpa

Comment: This seems very similar to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850380/xml-parsing-with-xslt I think you should be able to do the necessary adjustments yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the followig script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Stage[@Type = 'Movement']"/>

  <xsl:template match="@Type[matches(., 'Stage')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('N', substring(., 6))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Stage">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@Type"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nxtStart" select="
      (following-sibling::*[not(@Type = 'Movement')][1]/@Start, 50000)[1]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', $nxtStart, '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The template matching `Stage[@Type = 'Movement']` filters out
lines with Type="Movement".

The next template, matching `@Type[matches(., 'Stage')]` performs
translation of `Stage` to `N`.

And finally the last template, matching `Stage` does the main job. It:

- Prints (possibly changed) value of `Type` atribute.
- Computes a variable (`nxtStart`) containing `Start` attribute in
  the next sibling, but excluding those with `Type = 'Movement'`, but
  if it is absent, the "surrogate" value is `50000`.
- Prints the rest of what should be printed.